# Subversion project history not importing to Git correctly

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I just recently got around to converting an old svn project to git. Everything has worked fine except for one part of the history import.

For some reason the Commit number is way off. For example the first commit to the subversion repo was 1; but if I check the git log it reads that same commit as 53267272343. Just a little off :)

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has no commit version from 1 by 1. It's allways a hashcode. So you can have your commit with somthing else than that.

If you see in your commit log you can see that commit message say what svn commit it his with his number in svn versionning.

Comment: The svn commit information is usually included in the git commit message as you suggest, but the `--no-metadata` option is commonly used doing a full conversion from svn to git.  In that case, the svn information is elided from the commit log.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that commits were a hashcode in git. Thank you.